# Multinode data with eosjs

Tags: eosjs, node, multi

I need to prepare eosio dashboard for that I need multi nodes information.
I am using `eosjs` **nodejs** library to get genesis node chain information. Can I get which other nodes are connected with genesis node and their status information using `eosjs`? If yes, then how? Or what are the other ways? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is possible if your `nodeos` has the `net_api_plugin` enabled, and you connect to the endpoint `/v1/net/connections` However I haven't managed to get that to work yet on my local computer. Hopefully that is a starting point for you and if you make it further then you should update here with your answer.

I will also try again, and if I figure it out I'll update this answer

Comment: after connecting the endpoint `/v1/net/connections` it returns the list of peers with each peer's information.

Comment: @Varsh Glad you finally solved it :P